# No longer able to access shared calendars via Google Calendar API using service account

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I had a small php script working for a couple of months which could create and update google calendar events via the Google Calendar API. It was working for 2 months and then suddenly ceased to work despite no changes that I can find.

The code still works if I change the calendarId to be "primary" (which is the only true calendar the service account owns). So I know the code itself works in terms of creating the event, it just doesn't work to access the shared calendars to create events on those calendars. Here is how I setup the code initially and what I've tried:

1) I created the service account and granted it the "Owner" role. Then I created the key. (Note this is a GSuite account where I have enabled "Enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation").

2) For each calendar I needed to manage with the account, I went into the calendar share settings ("Share with specific people") and added the service account "email" with the permission "Make changes and manage sharing".

3) The PHP script is pretty basic as well and uses the latest version of the Google API PHP Client Library. It authenticates and then can create an event (note that a couple of details are changed like my app name to obscure some details).

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Got the data and ready to authenticate
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("MyAppName");
$client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
$client->setScopes([Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY,Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR]);
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

// GATHER ALL PASSED IN DATA INTO VARIABLES
$calendarId = 'mycalendar@group.calendar.google.com';
$summary = "Test calendar entry";
$startDate = "2019-02-19";
$endDate = "2019-02-19";
$attendees = "user1@domain.com,user2@domain.com";

//Construct event array to send
$eventArray = array(
    'summary' => $summary,
    'start' => array(
        'date' => $startDate,
        'timeZone' => 'America/Chicago',
    ),
    'end' => array(
        'date' => $endDate,
        'timeZone' => 'America/Chicago',
    ),
    'guestsCanInviteOthers' => true,
    'guestsCanModify' => true,
    'guestsCanSeeOtherGuests' => true
);

//Only include attendees in event array if we find them
if ($data["attendees"]) {
    // Attendees are present
    $attendees = explode(",", $data["attendees"]);
    $attendeesArray = array();
    foreach ($attendees as $key => $value) {
        $attendeesArray[$key]['email'] = $value;
    };

    //Now add to original event array
    $eventArray["attendees"] = $attendeesArray;

}

//Create the event and return event id
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event($eventArray);
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
$eventId = $event->id;
$createdDate = $event->created;
```

This is able to authenticate OK, but once you start working with a calendar other than "primary" it gives the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
    "error": {
    "errors": [
    {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
    }
    ],
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found"
    }
}
```

I've searched via google, reviewed many tutorials and suggestions on this site and everything I've tried including reset of the service account completely has not resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if Google changed how this worked or if my IT messed with the settings, as I know this was working for a while. However, I did find the fix!

Another setting had to be changed, which can only be set by a GSuite administrator. Here are the steps:

1. In your Google Admin console (at admin.google.com)...
2. Go to Apps > G Suite > Calendar.
   ( This requires having the Calendar > Settings administrator privilege. )
3. Click Sharing settings.
4. In the External Sharing options section, select "Share all information, and outsiders can change calendars"
5. If I recall correctly I didn't even need to click save and the setting was instant (regardless of the message saying it could take a while).

Full details found here - https://support.google.com/a/answer/60765?hl=en.